# Construct a random time such that the strong Markov property of Brownian motion fails

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{B_t, \mathcal{F}_t; t\ge 0\}$ be a standard, one-dimensional Brownian motion. Can we construct a random time $S$ such that $P[0\le S < \infty] = 1$ and $W_t = B_{S+t} - B_S$ is not a Brownian motion?

Comment: Of course we can! For example, set $S$ to be the *last* time $t$ such that $B_t = -t$. Then $W_t > -t$ for every $t$, and hence $W_t$ is not a Brownian motion.

Comment: Or, perhaps even simpler: let $S$ be the first time $t$ such that $B_{t+1} = B_t$. Then $W_1 = 0$ with probability one.

Comment: I don't understand. Is not $P[S < \infty] = 0$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka: You mean in Mateusz's first example, where $S$ is the last time that $B_t = -t$?  No, this is finite a.s., using for instance the strong law of large numbers.

Comment: Thank you, guys! Your comments are really helpful!